# Auto-update products after they were published - Woocommerce

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Octolooks Scrapes plugin for scraping products and automatically importing them to customers website. All imports are working fine, also publishing them and updating them automatically every hour... The only problem is stock!

- Products are imported correctly with meta "0" or "1" to **_stock** field in Woocommerce.
- Inventory managenet set on "yes".

But stock data is not recognized correctly when products are automatically published.

- Out of stock products are hidden from Shop page, but they are still counted in categories in sidebar for an example.
- Also they can not be sorted by stock in Woocommerce products dashboard...

BUT WHEN I update or in another words re-publish these same products again in Woocommerce, then all stock is set as it suppose to be. And If I would find solution to update products after they were published, It would do the trick.

On 1. image below it can be seen that product count is "0", but stock is **"In stock (0)"**:

[image]

On 2. image - stock correctly set **"Out of stock (0)"** and correct product count "0" recognized also in categories

[image]

Additional info:

- It doesn't help to regenerate Lookup table
- It doesn't help to clear the product/shop transients cache

Comment: Hi MacDesigns, please improve the "layout" of you questions. Don't write everything as one large text paragraph. 

Generally. Do you have some caching plugin, looks like some invalidation is missing when the sync finished.

Comment: Adrian, Hi! Thx for the warning, I'll correct the text. I already tried deactivating all plugins, except Woocommerce and Scrapes, but everything is the same. Same issue is also with Product Import Export for WooCommerce plugin with which I did the test, where I exported same product and then Importing it again, but the problem was the same...

Comment: Better If I say, the problem was ALMOST the same. with Product Import Export for WooCommerce plugin was correctly marked as **Out of stock (0)** on dashboard, but to accept correct stock status also in categories count on Product filter, I had to change the stock on 1 (In stock) and then back to 0 (out of stock) to except the changes.